# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') in <img/> tag

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

const DataPage = ({ Data }) => {
  const dataList = Data;
  console.log(dataList);

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <ul className='card-container'>
        {dataList && dataList.length > 0 ? (
          dataList.map((items) => (
            <li key={items?.data[0]?.nasa_id}>
              <img src={items.links[0]?.href} alt="logo" />
              <p>{items.data[0].title}</p>
            </li>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No data available</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataPage
```

After Running the the server Showing Error in <img/> Tag

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Hey, it's kinda hard to help you out without having an example of the data that you're receiving. I would imagine that `items?.data` or `items.link` is `undefined`. Btw, you can still use optional chaining when using the subscript operator `[]` as such: `items?.data?.[0]`. If you apply that and update your conditional rendering logic with that in mind you can probably fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add ? before [0]
items.links[0]?.href -> items.links?.[0]?.href

```
import React from 'react';
    const DataPage = ({ Data }) => {
    const dataList = Data;
    console.log(dataList);
    return (
    <div className='card'>
      <ul className='card-container'>
        {dataList && dataList.length > 0 ? (
          dataList.map((items) => (
            <li key={items?.data[0]?.nasa_id}>
              <img src={items.links?.[0]?.href} alt="logo" />
              <p>{items.data[0].title}</p>
            </li>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No data available</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataPage
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';

const DataPage = ({ Data }) => {
  const dataList = Data;
  console.log(dataList);

  return (
    <div className='card'>
      <ul className='card-container'>
        {dataList && dataList.length > 0 ? (
          dataList.map((items) => (
            <li key={items?.data?.[0]?.nasa_id}>
             <img src={items.links?.[0]?.href} alt="logo" />
              <p>{items.data?.[0].title}</p>
            </li>
          ))
        ) : (
          <p>No data available</p>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DataPage
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps before you do anything why don't you print out the value of Data so you know what you have?  Seems like you may have an empty array as others elude to.

```
console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(Data));
```

or something equivalent has help me many many times.